# Compiling different source files with different flags

Tags: c++, makefile

My makefile currently is:

```
# Environment
...
CC=gcc
CCC=g++
CXX=g++

# Macros
...

# Object Files
OBJECTFILES= \
    ${OBJECTDIR}/_ext/511e4115/File1.o \
    ${OBJECTDIR}/_ext/511e4115/File2.o
    
# CC Compiler Flags
CCFLAGS=-m64 -fno-common -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -fexceptions -fopenmp -Wall -Wextra
CXXFLAGS=-m64 -fno-common -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -fexceptions -fopenmp -Wall -Wextra
```

Is it possible at this stage to have:

```
CCFLAGS_DIFF=-m64 -fno-common -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -fexceptions -fopenmp
CXXFLAGS_DIFF=-m64 -fno-common -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -fexceptions -fopenmp
```

The difference between the original `CCFLAGS, CXXFLAGS` and the later `CCFLAGS_DIFF, CXXFLAGS_DIFF` is that the latter does not have `-Wall -Wextra`.

I want to selectively apply the later flags (the ones with `_DIFF`) to `File2.cpp` below while `File1.cpp` gets compiled with the original flags.

```
//Makefile continues

${OBJECTDIR}/_ext/511e4115/File1.o: ../src/File1.cpp
    ${MKDIR} -p ${OBJECTDIR}/_ext/511e4115
    ${RM} "$@.d"
    $(COMPILE.cc) -O2 -DNDEBUG -I../include -std=c++14 -MMD -MP -MF "$@.d" -o ${OBJECTDIR}/_ext/511e4115/File1.o ../src/File1.cpp

${OBJECTDIR}/_ext/511e4115/File2.o: ../src/File2.cpp
    ${MKDIR} -p ${OBJECTDIR}/_ext/511e4115
    ${RM} "$@.d"
    $(COMPILE.cc) -O2 -DNDEBUG -I../include -std=c++14 -MMD -MP -MF "$@.d" -o ${OBJECTDIR}/_ext/511e4115/File2.o ../src/File2.cpp
```

As of now, it is not clear to me where exactly the original flags, `CCFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS` are referred to. As a result, `File2.cpp` gets compiled with `-Wall -Wextra`.

Comment: I suggest silencing the specific warnings that you don't want with `-Wno-<the_warning>` for `File1.cpp` and `File2.cpp`. Small note: Instead of doing `mkdir` every time `File1.cpp` or `File2.cpp` has changed, make `File1.o` and `File2.o` dependant on the directory and create a recipe for that too. [example](https://pastebin.com/rdF4Qty6)

Comment: @TedLyngmo I use the makefile as generated by `NetBeans` ide and have found that to be quite useful in most cases but not this. Could you let me know, if you do, where exactly `CCFLAGS` is being referred to in the command? I would suppose that it happens in `$(COMPILE.cc)` but what is difficult for me to figure out is how this is supposed to refer to `CCFLAGS`, if at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`COMPILE.cc` is a built-in variable:

```
COMPILE.cc = $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH) -c
```

and you can override variables on a per-rule level, so with the following Makefile:

```
CXXFLAGS := all the rules 
CXXFLAGS_DIFF := $(subst all the, fewer, $(CXXFLAGS))
bad.o: CXXFLAGS=$(CXXFLAGS_DIFF)
```

I get:

```
% make -n good.o
c++ all the rules   -c -o good.o good.cc
% make -n bad.o
c++ fewer rules   -c -o bad.o bad.cc
```

Comment: Thanks for information on the built in variable. I will try the following and update if it worked. Instead of what you suggest, I think a cleaner way (if possible) would be to define: `COMPILE_DIFF.cc = $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS_DIFF) $(CPPFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH) -c`. Then, instead of having `bad.o` overriding `CXXFLAGS`, one should be able to call `$(COMPILE_DIFF.cc) -O2 -DNDEBUG ...` for the selected files.

Comment: That works too. Keep in mind that your changes will be lost if Netbeans decides to rewrite the file, while you can keep the target-specific rules in a separate file and just re-include that one file if the Makefile gets rewritten.

Comment: is there a way to figure out the value of the built-in variables in a version of gcc/g++/make? Does this change from one version to another? For instance, could you specify how you found out the exact value of the built-in variable that you posted in your answer?

Comment: `make -n -p -f /dev/null` prints the rules database given an empty Makefile, which gives you the built-in database rules.